# cant download from home page

Tags: download, iso

for last 2 days i'am trying to download ISO but every time i get:

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.

the link is https://ams3.dl.elementary.io/download/MTU4NjMzNDE5NQ==/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200405.iso

tried on from different brosers, notebook and so on, no add block etc is used.

Comment: Stranged... Just tested on eos with chromebrowser and it works very well. Are you behind a firewall? What about your IPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://nyc3.dl.elementary.io/download/MTU4NjMzNDE5NQ==/elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200405.iso

Some CDN addresses used by Elementary are censor-blocked in parts of the world.

Comment: thanks, it worked!